# How to auto-scroll to the bottom of a div perpetually?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom-events

I have a `<div>` with scrolling. Through JavaScript I add elements to the `<div>` with `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight`. Works great except I have to do that every time an element is added to the `<div>`. Is there a way to auto-scroll (without using `setInterval` and repeatedly scrolling over and over) and keep the `<div>`'s scrollbar pegged to the bottom?

My `<div>`:

```
<div class="messages" style="height: 7em; overflow: scroll">
  <div>Anonymous: Hello</div>
  <div>John: Hi</div>
</div>
```

Is there a `<div>` event for when the content changes?

**UPDATE**: I don't have easy access to JavaScript code *after* the `<div>` is added. That's why I'd love to add an event listener or some other mechanism to keep the scroll bar pegged to the bottom.

Comment: Why did you use setInterval? You should just scroll if there's a new event happening.

Comment: More specifically: only scroll to bottom when adding a new element *and you're already at bottom before it*, or your users will hate you.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with doing `element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight` after an element is added to the `<div>`.

Comment: You might want the `MutationObserver` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver , however, why not just call a scroll function after manipulating the DOM if it is done by your own code?

Comment: can you at least post your js code? @at

Comment: @LaraBelle, I said I **don't** want a `setInterval` solution... I'd love to scroll upon an event, but what event? @Amadan, I agree about not scrolling to bottom unless already at bottom before adding an element. First I need to figure out how to scroll to the bottom to begin with :). @josephting, there's something wrong with that code if I don't have the ability to add it :).

Comment: Sorry. My bad la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite the `addChild` method of the target element **or** you can use the `MutationOvserver` to observe the DOM.

given HTML:

```
<div id="messages-out" class="messages" style="height: 7em; overflow: scroll">
  <div>Anonymous: Hello</div>
  <div>John: Hi</div>
</div>
<input id="txtMessage" type="text" autofocus>
```

overwritten method approach:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev)
{
  var msgs = document.getElementById('messages-out');
  msgs.appendChild = function(childNode)
  {
    Element.prototype.appendChild.call(msgs, childNode);
    msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
  }

  document.getElementById('txtMessage').addEventListener('keypress', function(ev)
  {
    if(13 === ev.which)
    {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = '<em>nick: </em>' + ev.target.value;
      msgs.appendChild(div);
      ev.target.value = '';
    }
  });
})
```

MutationObserver approach:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(ev) {
  var
    msgs     = document.getElementById('messages-out'),
    observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations)
    {
      var added = false;

      mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if ('childList' === mutation.type && 0 < mutation.addedNodes.length)
          added = true;
      });

      if (added)
        msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
    })
  ;

  observer.observe(msgs, {childList: true});

  document.getElementById('txtMessage').addEventListener('keypress', function(ev)
  {
    if(13 === ev.which)
    {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = '<em>nick: </em>' + ev.target.value;
      msgs.appendChild(div);
      ev.target.value = '';
    }
  });

});
```

Note: It is not sure that the `element.appendChild` method is used to add a message, e.g. a child could be appended as in in the line `Element.prototype.appendChild.call(msgs, childNode);` or by `insertBefore`. So the second approach is more the "catch all" one.

Comment: The `MutationObserver` was exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks @Quasimodo's clone.

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable `var index = 0`. Add  `tabIndex` attribute to the dynamically created element with `index` set as `.value` of `tabIndex` attribute. Call `.focus()` on dynamically created element after appending element to parent element.

```
var index = 0;
```

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("tabIndex", index);
document.querySelector(".messages").appendChild(div);
div.focus();
++index;
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var messages = document.querySelector(".messages");
  var index = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("tabIndex", index);
    div.innerHTML = "abc";
    messages.appendChild(div);
    div.focus();
    ++index;
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<div class="messages" style="height: 7em; overflow: scroll">
  <div>Anonymous: Hello</div>
  <div>John: Hi</div>
</div>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/34QUtpGNVfho2fmYIlUI?p=preview

Comment: Nice unique approach. I never thought div can be focus. (+1)

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately it won't work for my situation as people need to be typing while messages come in... similar to a chat app. Can't be constantly taking away focus while they type :)